# Update play services android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

Hey my avd keeps telling me to update my google play services to show my map fragment. Unfortunatly I already updated the google play services already.

**Google play service versions installed**

- 26.0.0
- 26.0.1

I dont know what to do I already rebooted android studio and created a new avd.

Is this a known bug?

Heres the screen I get when I start the app

[image: Screenshot]

when I press the update button I get an activityNotFound Exception

Comment: What is your google play service version?

Comment: What version of Play Services are you using in your app?

Comment: sorry for the late answer..
my version is: 10.9.30 (470-155807809)
in my extended controls for the emulator is also no playservices tab is that a problem?

Comment: You need to update your emulator Android version. This might because of emulator's Android SDk might have old version of play services.

Comment: I am working on the last android o version that was not the problem I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally updated play service the key was to install the play store via sdk tools (extend packages) and create a nexus 5 emulator. On this emulator the update button works so I clicked it and logged in with my google acc. It opened the play store with the play services which I could update.